# Beginning a sentence with "alors" or "donc"

Tags: usage, adverbes, conjonctions

In writing, is it appropriate to begin a sentence with *alors* or *donc* to mean "so"/"therefore"? For example:

> Samedi dernier il a plu toute la journée. Alors/donc elle a décidé de rester à la maison et de faire la lessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly correct. Starting with alors/donc is a stylistic effect to insist that the second sentence is a consequence of the first.

I would say :

> Alors elle a décidé ...

or

> Elle a donc décidé ...

IMHO,

> Donc elle a décidé ...

would be a little stronger, but it is more a matter or taste than anything else...